# Phonegap cannot create app - not a valid template

Tags: linux, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I'm trying to create an app through the command:

```
phonegap create myApp
```

and the output is:

```
(node:22583) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of 
module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Creating a new cordova project. 
/tmp/cordova-create--22590-8UKcFmkwV57y/node_modules/phonegap-template-hello-world 
is not a valid template
```

I've tried changing the template such as `--template blank` but still no available. I've also searched the internet for related questions but there seems to be none.

Comment: Use flutter for cross-platform mobile app development

Comment: We use it for school so I have to stick with it for now

Comment: PhoneGap has been unfortunately been discontinued. You could ask your school to contact VoltBuilder, Ionic or Monaca to see if they can help.